# Custom Arrayadapter geview() is not called

Tags: android

my `getview()` method in custom arrayadapter is not calling,i searched more but i cant able to find the solution,please provide me some suggestion.i think i done almoost all the possibility ways but i cant able to fix it.

Here is my Activity

```
public ListView listView;
TwiterlistAdapter adapter;
List<ProfileconnectedObject> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wood_twitlist);

    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    list=new ArrayList<ProfileconnectedObject>();

    adapter=new TwiterlistAdapter(Wood_Twiter_Feed_list.this, R.layout.wood_twititem, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Here is my adapter

```
public class TwiterlistAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ProfileconnectedObject>{
public Context context;
List<ProfileconnectedObject> items;
ProfileconnectedObject object;
private RadioButton mCurrentlyCheckedRB;
private boolean userSelected = false;
private int mResourceId = 0;
private RadioButton mSelectedRB;
private int mSelectedPosition = -1;
int row;

public TwiterlistAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        List<ProfileconnectedObject> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.row=resource;
    this.context=context;
    this.items=objects;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("items.size() "+items.size());
    return this.items.size();
}
public Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    View hView = convertView;
    if (hView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(row, null);

        holder.pic = (ImageView) hView
                .findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
        holder.name = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.radiobt = (RadioButton) hView.findViewById(R.id.radio);
        hView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) hView.getTag();
    }

    object=items.get(position);


    if (position == getCount() - 1 && userSelected == false) {
        holder.radiobt.setChecked(true);
        mCurrentlyCheckedRB = holder.radiobt;
    } else {
        holder.radiobt.setChecked(false);
    }


    holder.radiobt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if((position != mSelectedPosition && mSelectedRB != null)){
                mSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
            }

            mSelectedPosition = position;
            mSelectedRB = (RadioButton)v;
        }
    });

    if(mSelectedPosition != position){
        holder.radiobt.setChecked(false);
    }else{
        holder.radiobt.setChecked(true);
        if(mSelectedRB != null && holder.radiobt != mSelectedRB){
            mSelectedRB = holder.radiobt;
        }
    }

   holder.name.setText(object.getP_profilename());
    return hView;

}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    RadioButton radiobt;
    ImageView pic;
}
```

}

Comment: Change this

     `convertView = inflater.inflate(row, null);`

to
    
     `hView = inflater.inflate(row, null);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list object is empty **list=new ArrayList();**. So the getView() method will not be called. Add some values into that arraylist and try. You need to put values inside the arraylist between these statements.

```
listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

list=new ArrayList<ProfileconnectedObject>();
/* For Example */
list.add(new ProfileconnectedObject());

adapter=new TwiterlistAdapter(Wood_Twiter_Feed_list.this, R.layout.wood_twititem, list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Try to Add some object values into the arraylist and check again.

Comment: Thanks for reply,having one doubt,iam storing all the values at the time of login itself,then why it showing as empty

Comment: yes i stored it in List<ProfileconnectedObject> items at the time of login,whether i need to stored it again

Comment: hi , tried but it gives error,i changed the arrarylist in login as static and in next activity i crated something like this,

Comment: List<ProfileconnectedObject> list=new ArrayList<ProfileconnectedObject>();list=Woosuite_Login.items;

Comment: it saying list is empty

Comment: Did you give the visibility as public? What was the error you got?

Comment: its working,my mistake only,thanks for the help,one more doubt here iam printing profile names which from arraylist in the listview but it printing the last values only,may i know why

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {      
       JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);      
       obj_twit=new TwiterProfilesConnected();      
      obj.setP_profilename(jsonObject.getString(P_PROFILENAME));
      items.add(obj);       
      }

Comment: i print the values it showing different names only but while in listview all values are same

Comment: You are great,that the point,why we need to create object again and again?

Comment: Ok now you could delete all the comments in this answer because these comments are not related to the question which you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't left anything out, your list is empty. Check the size of the list in getCount(), I'm pretty sure its 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try Like this :

    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Listviewname);
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    AssignmentDatabaseConnector dao = new AssignmentDatabaseConnector(getActivity());
            List<AssignmentPojo> assignments= dao.getAllAssignmentList();
            assignmentCustomAdapter = new AssignmentCustomAdapter(getActivity(),
                    assignments, this);
            listView.setAdapter(assignmentCustomAdapter);
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ##AssignmentDatabaseConnector :

    public List<AssignmentPojo> getAllAssignmentList() {
            open();
            List<AssignmentPojo> assignmentList = new ArrayList<AssignmentPojo>();
            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM Assignment";

            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    AssignmentPojo assignment = new AssignmentPojo();
                    assignment.setAssign_Id(cursor.getString(0));
                    assignment.setAssign_Course(cursor.getString(1));

                    // Adding contact to list
                    assignmentList.add(assignment);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
            database.close();
            // return contact list
            return assignmentList;
        }
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#AssignmentCustomAdapter.java :

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.xyz.R;
    import com.xyz.pojo.AssignmentPojo;

    public class AssignmentCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private TextView mAssignTitle, mAssignCourse, mAssignAvDate, mAssignAvTime,
                mAssignClDate, mAssignClTime;
        private final Context context;
        List<AssignmentPojo> assignments;
        private ViewAllAssignments viewAllAssignments;




        AssignmentCustomAdapter(Context context, List<AssignmentPojo> assignments2,
                ViewAllAssignments viewAllAssignments) {
            this.context = context;
            this.assignments = assignments2;
            this.viewAllAssignments = viewAllAssignments;


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return assignments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View rowView = convertView;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (convertView == null) {
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.assignments_viewlists, parent,
                        false);
            }

            mAssignCourse = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Assign_Course);
            mAssignCourse.setText(assignments.get(position).getAssign_Course());

            mAssignTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Assign_Title);


            SingleChk = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.SingleChk);

            checkedvalue.clear();


            rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // Toast 
                }
            });



            return rowView;
        }

    }
```